# How to use Positioned widget to position at top right corner on stack

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to position my object on top right corner in a stack.
This is what I have. I know if I set all(LTRB) to 0.0 the image is placed in the center. Is there a simpler way for me to place the image on the upper right corner ?

```
Widget _buildRemoveIcon()
    {
        return Positioned(
            top:0.0,
            left:60.0,
            right: 0.0,
            bottom:0.0,
            child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: new IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(
                            Icons.cancel,
                            color: Colors.red,
                            ),
                        onPressed: () {
                        }), //
                ),
            );
    }
```

Answer (score 22):

Just remove the `left` and `bottom` parameters from `Positioned` widget to align your widget to the top right corner.

Example:

```
Positioned(
  top:0.0,
  right: 0.0,
  child: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    child: new IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.cancel,color: Colors.red,),
      onPressed: () {}),
  ),
)
```

[image]

Comment: How to add a plus icon at the top right corner of another circula image in widget dynamically for all devices? like a circular profile pic icon with an add image at right corner of it.

Comment: Use a `Stack` widget with the `profilePic` widget and the `plus` button as `children`. And then align the `plus` button to top right as given in the answer

Answer (score 10):

You can use the [`Align`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Align-class.html) widget:

```
Align(
  alignment: Alignment.topRight,
  child: ...
);
```